# best practice for offline tool with database

Tags: database, search, client

In my internship i have to program a tool which should basically have filtering and search options for a database (which i have to update sometimes - probably in csv format) and which should be usable offline as well as online.

I was first thinking about creating a webtool with indexeddb but had several issues there (and indexeddb doenst support full text search)

Setting up a local webserver for a mysql database for example was my next idea, but then i also have to create server side code and cannot do something like live search and manipulating data on the clientside only. (without much effort)

do any of you guys have an idea for the simplest solution for an easy offline tool with nice GUI for filtering databases and doing full text search in the DB?
Programming language is secondary if you have good solutions for it

Comment: Have you looked at SQLite? I know it has full text search, but I'm not sure it meets your needs.

Comment: yeah i considered that too, but still the same problem as with mysql that i have to build server side code even if i only have a clientside application. and also no "live" search

Comment: So is this tool meant to be used by multiple users?

Comment: multiple devices, but no user management necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite locally and MySQL/MariaDB on the external server. Probably you'll have to come up with some synchronization mechanism, but fortunately there is quite a lot of information about that on the Internet as this is quite common problem nowadays with mobile apps synchronizing with external databases. Try searching for "android sqlite synchronize mysql" and you'll find tons of info (both theory and code snippets) and also links to some free and open-source replication solutions (e.g. http://www.symmetricds.org/).